# Write values from multidimensional array to csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I wrote a small Java program that reads the data from CSV file and I have to save these values in 2 dimensional array. Now I need to write these values (not all information will be stored because the array contains many redundant data) from this array to a new CSV file. Can anyone help me with a code sample, I searched a lot but could not find an answer. My code is:

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
String[][] numbers=new String[24][24];

File file = new File("D:\\thesis\\sorted_file.csv");
if(file.exists())
{
    System.out.println("file exist");
}   

BufferedReader bufRdr;
bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
String delims=",";

//read each line of text file
while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null )
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,delims);

    col=0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        //get next token and store it in the array
        numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
        System.out.print("number["+row+"]["+col+"]:"+numbers[row][col]);
        col++;
    }
    row++;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this...

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String element : numbers) {
sb.append(element);
sb.append(",");
}

br.write(sb.toString);
br.close();
```

Comment: I tried to use this but it has error on  br.write(sb.toString); and the error is (toString cannot be resolved or not a field) and the other error is {for (String element : number)} number can not be resolved to a variable